# Cloned disk isn't bootable

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone

I have a Macbook Pro which has a Windows installation on one of the partitions. I bought a new desktop with a new SSD and wanted my Windows install from my Macbook on the new SSD. So I cloned the partition onto the new SSD with OSX's Disk Utility, put it in my new desktop and tried it. Turns out windows has a separate partition containing stuff for booting so my clone was unbootable.

Does anyone know a way that I can get this new drive to boot? Alternatively, if you know any way of creating a bootable clone I'm happy to just clone it again properly.

Comment: Acronis now have a clone utility that can do Boot Camp partitions; otherwise you need WinClone. Don't let Windows play with Mac partitions.

Comment: A cloned drive won't work properly unless it's used in the same system. Windows keeps track of the hardware that's connected while it's installing. You might be able to get it working, but it won't be as flawless as it would be if you make a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers an all-in-one command to restore booting: `bcdboot`. Start from a Windows Install disc/USB and enter command prompt by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Then, find your system partition (henceforth `C:`) and run `bcdboot`:

```
c:\windows\system32\bcdboot c:\windows
```

This will install the boot loader either on the active partition on the primary disk or, if that doesn’t exist, the same partition as Windows. You can also explicitly specify the desired partition, like this:

```
c:\windows\system32\bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

---

That being said, cloning or moving an installation to a totally different PC is not a great idea. Only do it if you absolutely have to.

Comment: Golden Rule - never let Windows play with the partitioning on a Mac drive. It just doesn't understand the structure.

Comment: @Tetsujin He’s no longer on his Mac, but rather his new PC.

Comment: hmmm… 'desktop' was a bit non-specific; could be either I guess, now you mention it